# How to call a method in a multi-threaded way that returns elements of a List

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have this method:

```
    public List<String> composeList (DataBaseObject dBO) {
    List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
       for (String separatedFieldName : separatedFieldNames) {
           object = PropertyUtils.getProperty(object, separatedFieldName);
           valueList.add(object.toString());
       }                        
    }
```

I have a list of 1000 dBO objects and would like to call this method in a multi-threaded way.

But the return of this method also goes into a list

Here is the caller:

```
List<List<String>> valueLists =  new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataBaseObject dBO : listOfDBOs)
    valueLists.add(composeList(dBOObject));
```

Since the machines now a days have multiple cores, I was wondering how can I make use of them. Like how do I call composeList in parellel and store results in one ArrayList.

I know I can use the Collections.SynchronizedList but then the execution time of composeList is so little that I will end up adding elements in a sequence and even though being multi-threaded it would still be sequential execution as every add will put a lock on the Sysnchronized list.

This might sound like a design question but still it is programming related. And I would really appreciate any help with this situation.

Comment: I don't think you can safely write to the an object at the same time. You could have call your list populator while running another task, but not have two tasks editing the same list at the same time. That's why SynchronizedLists are basically sequential behaviour when used like this, it's the only safe way to do it.

Comment: Like I said this need not be a problem related to List population.. May be you can suggest something with the design as well. Unfortunately I have to wait for the list population to complete for the next task to happen. So cannot call anything else in the mean time.

Comment: It is not clear in you example, why addition to `valueList` is outside of loop. As I understand, you going to add all values of all fields?

Comment: @KenBekov Oh sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 parallel streams are designed for exactly this situation.

```
List<String> dbFieldValues = dbObjectList.parallelStream()
    .flatMap(seperatedFieldNames().parallelStream()
        .map(fn -> PropertyUtils.getProperty(db, fn).toString()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Assuming the collection of `seperatedFieldNames` supports parallel streams (e.g. `ArrayList`) this will use multiple threads without any need to create them yourself.

Note that this assumes there are no side-effects to `getProperty`.

Comment: Your answer is on the dot but unfortunately at least for now I cannot migrate the application to use Java8

Answer (score 0):

Possible, this solution little bit "traditional style" without any cool new things, like *stream* etc, but I would do something like following:

```
public class AnyClass {

    private static final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static final Object lock = new Object();      

    public class ComposerThread implements Runnable {

        private List<DataBaseObject> dboList;
        private List<List<String>> valueList;
        private List<String> fieldNames;

        public MyThread(List<DataBaseObject> dboList, List<List<String>> valueList, 
                        List<String> fieldNames) {
            this.valueList= valueList;
            this.dboList = dboList;
            this.fieldNames = fieldNames;
        }

        public void run() {
            int i = index.getAndIncrement(); //thread takes next unprocessed index
            while(i<dboList.size()){
                DataBaseObject object = dboList.get(i);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String separatedFieldName : fieldNames) {
                    Object object = PropertyUtils.getProperty(object, separatedFieldName);
                    list.add(object.toString());
                }  

                synchronized (lock) {  //addition synchronized
                    valueList.add(list);
                }
                i = index.getAndIncrement(); //thread takes next unprocessed index
            }
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Note, that `AtomicInteger index` and `Object lock` have to be `final static`, because of usage in synchronization. Now you can use `ComposerThread` internal class in same parent class:

```
public class AnyClass{

    ....

    private List<List<String>> composeValueList(List<DataBaseObject> dboList,
                                                List<String> fieldNames, int threadCount) {

        index.set(0);//reset index before process dboList
        List<List<String>> valueList = new List<List<String>>();

        Thread [] pool = new Thread[threadCount];
        for(int i=0; i<pool.length; i++){
            pool[i] = new Thread(new ComposerThread (objectList, valueList, fieldNames));
            pool[i].start();
        }
        for(Thread thread : threadPool){
            thread.join(); //just wait while all will be done
        }
        return valueList;
    }
}
```

As you see, you even can set count of threads.

Answer (score -1):

Read about `ExecutorService` and `ForkJoin` frameworks in java. It may help you to achieve what you want.

thank you.